# Calling a function i javascript from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

New to js/html so help is needed.

i have this simple html file:

```
   <html>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js">

   var numOfRounds = 25;
   var result = startGame(numOfRounds,player1,player2 );
   document.write(result.p1+":"+result.p2);

   </script>

   </html>
```

and as you can see the function im calling to is startGame(...)

this is the function:

```
   function startGame(rounds, player1, player2) {

       var counter = 0;
       while (counter < rounds) {
       player1.itemChosen = player1.play();
       player2.itemChosen = player2.play();

      player1.feedback(player2.itemChosen);
      player2.feedback(player1.itemChosen);

      counter++;
   }
   return  {p1: player1.getW(),p2: player2.getW() }

  };
```

but for some reason when i try to debug it (chrome) the startGame function is not 
called at all.

any ideas?

Comment: And this was down voted because...?

Comment: @Andrew My thought exactly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have any code inside a script tag with a src attribute.

Either use a script tag with a src attribute, or a script tag without src attribute and with code inside it, or both.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   var numOfRounds = 25;
   var result = startGame(numOfRounds,player1,player2 );
   document.write(result.p1+":"+result.p2);

   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have any code inside a script tag with a src attribute.

if you want to use any other variable or component of attribute than you either use a script tag with a src attribute, or a script tag without src attribute and with code inside it, or both.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js">        </script>
```

than use another script like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var numOfRounds = 25;


 var result = startGame(numOfRounds,player1,player2 );



document.write(result.p1+":"+result.p2);



</script>
```

like this....

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your inline js in another script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

   var numOfRounds = 25;
   var result = startGame(numOfRounds,player1,player2 );
   document.write(result.p1+":"+result.p2);

</script>
```

I'm guessing startGame is declared in rps.js.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a script tag for the function try to add as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Your function code
</script>
```